# Spaces in JAVA_OPTS in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, linux, suse, tomcat5.5

How can I pass a property which has spaces using `JAVA_OPTS` to Apache Tomcat?

For example;

```
-Dmy.property="How are you"
```

My operating system is SUSE Linux.

Comment: just added OS to question ...its suse linux

Answer (score 2):

I actually figured this out using AWS Elasticbeanstalk, which lets you have spaces in the Environment Properties you can enter via the UI.

As part of the build of the server instance, the Elasticbeanstalk service replaces the /usr/bin/tomcat7 script in order to accommodate some of its requirements.

If you check this, you can see the following difference:

Default script:

```
if [ "$1" = "start" ]; then
    ${JAVACMD} $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
```

Elasticbeanstalk script:

```
if [ "$1" = "start" ]; then
    eval "${JAVACMD} $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
    ...."
```

ie they have placed an "eval" before the command to start the JVM, and enclosed the entire command in double-quotes.

This appears to allow the JAVA_OPTS values with spaces be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me there is no way to use spaces in JAVA_OPTS, I have the same problem on OSX.
You can add your property directly to other -D options in the catalina.sh

Answer (score 0):

Let's open file `$CATALINA_HOME\bin\catalina.sh` . You will see the guide from Apache Tomcat for variable `JAVA_OPTS`

```
#   JAVA_OPTS       (Optional) Java runtime options used when any command
#                   is executed.
#                   Include here and not in CATALINA_OPTS all options, that
#                   should be used by Tomcat and also by the stop process,
#                   the version command etc.
#                   Most options should go into CATALINA_OPTS.
```

You want set property `-Dmy.property="How are you"`, it is not a property that JVM supported. You should put it in variable `CATALINA_OPTS`. If your property's value has space(s), wrap it inside `" "`.

```
#   CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
#                   "run" or "debug" command is executed.
#                   Include here and not in JAVA_OPTS all options, that should
#                   only be used by Tomcat itself, not by the stop process,
#                   the version command etc.
#                   Examples are heap size, GC logging, JMX ports etc.
```

*(Although you used Apache Tomcat 5.5, I quoted guide from Apache Tomcat 9.0.11 because it is existing in my computer)*

Answer (score 0):

If embedded Tomcat >= 8.x.y is used with Spring Boot >= 2.4 as an optional solution one can use
**spring.config.import** in (default) application.properties file to introduce additional, externalized properties file,
e.g.:

> spring.config.import=file:/Users/app/data/config/extra-props.properties

If app is containerized, one could mount volume and place extra-props.properties in mounted location.

Specific properties with spaces or asterisk can be used in that additional file. Example case would be cron expression with special characters, e.g.:

> server.schedule.cron.exp=*/20 * * * * *

[Ref: docs.spring.io:2.7.4:spring.config.import](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.4/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.spring.config.import)

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
-Dmy.property="How\ are\ you"
```

Comment: Confirmed, this definitely does not work. It does not seem possible to escape spaces in any way.